# Opera is unable to play videos in MX Linux KDE version

Tags: video, mx-linux, opera

I recently installed and started to use the Opera browser as it offers a wide range of functionality and the workspace feature: it seems very viable for me. But when it comes to playing videos, this browser is giving me lots of trouble. So let me add a screenshot to show what actually is happening here.

[image]

The same goes for Netflix; here is the screenshot.

[image]

Are there any workarounds to this problem? I really love this browser; I want to use it for this purpose.

Comment: Does youtube work?

Comment: Yes, youtube works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The packages of opera available in the package repository of every distro are outdated and old versions. However, the developer community of the Opera browser has fixed this problem; in my opinion hence, if you need to install and use the browser without any hassle, better download and install it from this website: [Download Opera](https://www.opera.com/download).